# marathon not run tasks

Tags: mesos, marathon

I am making mesos-cluster terraform provisioning.

Using marathon reflected the following problem:

tasks are queued only if the leader associated with marathon matches the same machine as the leader assigned to mesos-master.

Otherwise the endless waits.

Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: are there any warning or error logs on mesos master? i think that is connection problem between mesos and marathon.